# Why is their an order in which you assign a new variable to an existing one

Tags: python, variables

Why does this assign the string stored in x to y:

```
x = "string"
y = x
```

And this raise an error:

```
x = "string"
x = y
```

Comment: In your second example, `y` is not defined - what would you expect to happen if not an error?

Comment: Presumably you understand that `x = y` and `y = x` mean different things?

Comment: Those are *not* mathematical equations, they are assignment operations.

Comment: `=` does not equate two things; it's very much an asymmetric operation. It takes the value on the right-hand side and makes the left-hand side another name for it.

Comment: Imagine if `x = "string"` and `y = "other string"`. Would you expect `x = y` and `y = x` to do the same thing, and if so, what's the value of `x` and `y` after the assignment? Would it be `"string"` or `"other string"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator `=` (and its variants such as `+=`, `-=`, ...) in Python do not work the exact same way they do in mathematical formulas. That is, in Python (and most other non-functional languages), the operator assigns the result of the right-hand side expression to the variable on the left side of the `=` operator. Although it uses the same symbols used in a mathematical equation, it is not a mathematical equation expressing an abstract statement.

Your two statements are executed in order. As such

```
x = "string"
```

Assigns the object `"string"` to the variable `x`. The following statement

```
y = x
```

then assigns the object currently referenced by the `x` variable to the `y` variable, so that both variables point to the exact same object.

If you instead try to assign the non-existent variable `y` to `x`, you get an error, because `y` does not have a value assigned yet.

The `=` symbol is a very common symbol used for such assignment operations in many languages, including C, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, Perl, ... As a noteworthy exception, Delphi and its predecessors in the form of the various Pascal dialects use `:=` instead which may make the intention of an assignment clearer.

Also please note that to query if a variable has a certain value, you use the `==` operator (and its related operators). Here, you also diverge from the strict mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case,
'String' was attached to x (where x is a variable )
The variable x is then assigned to another variable y which makes sense mathematically and it's pythonic (since the variable x already stores a python datatype known as string)

In the second case,
A string datatype "string" was assigned to x.
In the next line, you attempted to reassign the variable x to y.
However y is not a datatype in python hence a Type Error will be thrown.

Please note that in python,
The Left hand side of an equality sign is a variable while the right hand side is the content (which must be a python datatype or another variable which already holds a python datatype )